# What's the best way to model these database associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord

So I have the following models:

- User
- Business
- Coupons
- Deals
- Redeemable
- owner

I am using the owner model to associate various other models such as business coupons deals and redeemable to the user model.

The redeemable model is used because I want to generate a unique code for each user that uses a coupon/deal in order to limit one per user as well as the amount in total.

I suppose maybe I don't need two models for coupon and deal and I just need one because a deal is more like a special type of coupon.

So heres the models after a revision:

```
Business
   has_many :owners, :as => :ownable, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :coupons, :dependent => :destroy

Coupon
   belongs_to :business
   has_many :redeems
   # also has a special column for denoting weather it's a 
   # normal coupon or a daily deal kind of coupon

Redeem
   belongs_to :coupon
   has_one :owner, :as => :ownable, :dependent => :destroy

Owner
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :ownable, :polymorphic => true
```

and for the user model I am just totally lost 
but here's what I want in pseudo code
   edit just for all those who may have same problem here's how i set up the user model

```
User
   has_many :owners
   has_many :businesses, :through => :owners, 
              :source => business, :source_type => 'Business'
   has_many :redeems, :through => :owners, :source=> :redeem, 
              :source_type => 'Redeem'

   has_many :coupons, :through => :redeems, 
              :source => :coupon, :source_type => 'Coupon'
```

I just don't understand how to associate the coupons with the User model because I did a polymorphic association for owning things.

Comment: Considering that redeemable is an adjective, that would place it as a property of an object or a column of a table. As a verb (redeem) it would be represented by an an association. You have it as an entity (object), so something is off here. Perhaps you could describe the process that you are trying to model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that a coupon is essentially a contract, a certificate, an instance of a deal. When a person buys a coupon, they actually buy a legal contract that some business will deliver on a promised product or service described in the contract (deal). So with that in mind, here is an attempt to model this.

[image]

Comment: wow thank you so much what did you use to create this chart? Anyway I don't think I was accurate in my explanation of what everything is meant to do I'm sorry. Deals and coupons were meant to offer different kinds of special offers. A deal is more like an instance of a coupon rather than vice verse. A deal has an expiration date and must be redeemed by then but one can only accept and pay for the deal for a limited amount of time. So a deal is basically like a daily deal. Whereas a coupon may be up to print out for a few months. I'll add this to the main question.

Comment: Also taking from the way you've modeled it I guess I shouldn't do a polymorphic association to see who the owner of a certain model is?

Comment: @Tyler Rice; for most ORM this can be done using simple `table per class` mapping.

Comment: @Demir Sudarevic  I think i figured it out and thanks for all the help I'll update my post on how I set it up and accept your answer